# Compiling Haskell on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: haskell, compilation, raspberry-pi, ghci, raspbian

I am trying to compile GHC 7.6.3 on the Raspberry Pi.
The 7.4 version of GHC that ships with Raspbian, does not support **ghci**.
I intend to package v 7.6.3 and make it available.

After a looong time, I get this error on the Pi:

```
HC [stage 0] utils/hp2ps/dist/build/Key.o
HC [stage 0] utils/hp2ps/dist/build/PsFile.o
HC [stage 0] utils/hp2ps/dist/build/Shade.o
HC [stage 0] utils/hp2ps/dist/build/Utilities.o
"inplace/bin/mkdirhier" utils/hp2ps/dist/build/tmp//.
HC [stage 0] utils/hp2ps/dist/build/tmp/hp2ps
Warning: -rtsopts and -with-rtsopts have no effect with -no-hs-main.
Call hs_init_ghc() from your main() function to set these options.
"cp" -p utils/hp2ps/dist/build/tmp/hp2ps inplace/bin/hp2ps
cp driver/ghc-usage.txt inplace/lib/ghc-usage.txt
cp driver/ghci-usage.txt inplace/lib/ghci-usage.txt
HC [stage 0] utils/genapply/dist/build/GenApply.o
"inplace/bin/mkdirhier" utils/genapply/dist/build/tmp//.
HC [stage 0] utils/genapply/dist/build/tmp/genapply
"cp" -p utils/genapply/dist/build/tmp/genapply inplace/bin/genapply
HC [stage 1] libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Types.o
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/bin/llc -O3 -relocation-model=static /tmp/ghc467_0/ghc467_0.bc  -o /tmp/ghc467_0/ghc467_0.lm_s --enable-tbaa=true 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/tmp/ghc467_0/ghc467_0.bc'.
2.  Running pass 'ARM Instruction Selection' on function '@ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_info'
/tmp/ghc467_0/ghc467_0.lm_s: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
make[1]: *** [libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Types.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

real    308m59.437s
user    292m8.320s
sys     10m18.220s
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

How can I end up with missing intermediate files, that are produced by the build system?

Comment: Looks like a bug somewhere in the build tool chain. Perhaps better try a cross compiler on a x86 system. The cross compiler is a weak link (very likely to expose some bugs) but at least the other tools are then quite well tested. See here for instructions (cross from x86 Linux to Raspberry Linux seems to be supported quite well): http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation

Comment: Debian provides [GHC 7.6.3 on arm](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ghc), so you might want to check out the ARM-related [Patched](http://patch-tracker.debian.org/package/ghc/7.6.3-3) applied by Debian.

Comment: Thank you guys. Actually I tried to temporarily switch to the sid repository to install ghc, but this ended up in a dependencies nightmare (it insisted to upgrade my libc). So I decided to compile it myself.

Comment: I tried to compile the Debian sid version of ghc on Raspberry Pi, and hit exactly the same error as you did. Tell if you can get the cross compilation working!

Comment: Ugh, spent the last two days compiling and also got to this point.  I wonder if the same problem exists on 7.8?  Might try compiling that.

Answer (score 3):

I got GHC-7.8.3 compiled with Raspberry PI from upstream sources. It's not very fast, but it gets the job done:

```
pi@arlanda ~ $ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> 1+1
2
```

Key things are to do the following:

1. Have enough memory. Plug in an external hard disk and create a 4-gigabyte swap partition. First in `fdisk` select the partition type to be Linux swap, then do `mkswap /dev/sdXX`, finally do swapon `/dev/sdXX`, where `XX` is the disk id letter and partition number.
2. Update kernel to the latest version with `rpi-update` to prevent hangs. I had also `smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N slub_debug=FP` added to the end of kernel command line in `/boot/cmdline.txt` file.
3. Install gold linker with `apt-get install binutils-gold`, because regular `ld.bfd` will fail to create the dynamic libraries. The problem is that you can't use `gold` for linking everything, but need to link the stage 1 with `ld.bfd`. You need to follow the instructions [in this script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bgamari/9399430/raw/build-ghc-arm.sh) ([original information from here](http://bgamari.github.io/posts/2014-03-06-compiling-ghc-7.8-on-arm.html)) with the exception that you need to use `ld.bfd` for running the initial `./configure` call too.
4. Have patience -- the compilation will take days.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to build GHC 7.8.3 on my ancient Rev1 Raspberry Pi following these instructions. I had to [adjust the GPU memory allocation](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/674) down to 16G as an additional step. It took one week to compile and I had to restart the compilation couple times as it got killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the official haskell page for R-Pi. Hope it helps you more than it helped me. There are some really useful links there.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Raspberry_Pi